# wired mouse wheel sensitivity adjustment

Tags: mouse, kubuntu

I just upgraded from Kubuntu 14.10 to Kubuntu 15.04, but a problem persists among all the versions I've tried since long ago: my usb mouse wheel don't behave as expected. Even if I turn it very slowly the scrolling windows (weather it's a web page on ANY browser, a long screen of text in a terminal, a page on LibreOffice, the virtual desktops on KDE Plasma, whatever), quickly goes back and forth a little, sometimes leading me to despair!  =(

Is there any way to adjust this behavior or at least the wheel sensitivity?

Thanks to you all in advance!